# Is there some way to get my Hadoop cluster information programatically?

Tags: java, api, hadoop

i am able to get information about my hadoop cluster using command line  with tools like

1. hadoop dfsadmin -report
2. hadoop fs -df -h

what we are trying to do is make decision when user requests(through webUI) based on remaining HDFS disk space and Yarn queues.

i was thinking if hadoop exposes some APIs to which we can fire 'GET' requests and get these information and use that to return response. any alternatives to these also would do.

i tried finding Hadoop Apis and got following results

```
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/
```

i dont see any url endpoints in the above link where i can make requests. Am i missing something fundamental?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java API: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getStatus()

The protocol to get this information from a namenode uses Google Protobuf.